# Best practice for reviewing LUIS Endpoint Utterances in a new version

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

As a best practice, I am trying to make use of [LUIS app versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-versions) when making changes to my LUIS model. This ensures that I can compare how different LUIS app versions perform, and allows me to easily roll back in case the predictions are not as expected.

I have Active Learning enabled, and want to [review LUIS Endpoint Utterances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-review-endpoint-utterances). However, I notice that the LUIS Endpoint Utterances are only available in the currently active version, and not copied over to a clone of the active version.

Is it correct that reviewing Endpoint Utterances can only be done directly in the active (production) version, and not in any new (cloned) version of the app, or did I miss something? What are your best practices for reviewing endpoint utterances without having to add them directly to the production-published version?

The only workaround I found is to [export all endpoint utterances of the last month via the API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c36) or via [LUIS CLI](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/249) (one by one for each intent..), and then manually apply these on the v2 cloned version, but I feel there should be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there must have been some hiccup or it might take some time in the back-end for the endpoint utterances to appear, since today they are displaying correctly under the new cloned version. Problem solved!